# ¿Cómo guardar un csv en python sin que me transforme los ceros a la izquierda?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Tengo un problema con la columna "code". El problema es que cuando guardo en un csv y lo abro en Excel, me transforma la columna "code" eliminando los ceros que a la izquierda (Ejem: "00042" 42). No se si es problema de cuando guardo el csv o cuando lo abro en Excel, ¿saben si se puede poner algún parametro en el .to_csv() para que no me borré nada de la cadena a guardar?

```
import pandas as pd 
a = {'code': ["00042", "34000","03434", "04344"], "num":[1, 3 ,5 ,53]}
A = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

A.to_csv("archivo.csv", index=False)
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Si abres el CSV con un editor de texto como sublime o el bloc de notas te salen los 0 ? Si es así tendrás que revisar cómo lo estás importando en Excel

Comment: Si cuando lo abro con un editor de texto si me aparecen los ceros. ¿Entonces es cuestión de Excel y no de como lo guardo?

Comment: Efectivamente es cosas del Excel, mira te adjunto un artículo para que veas como lo puedes importar . https://support.office.com/es-es/article/mantener-los-ceros-a-la-izquierda-y-grandes-cantidades-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7

Comment: @LuisDominguez "Son cosas de Excel". Tiene que haber una etiqueta `son-cosas-de-excel` porque siempre causa problemas.

Comment: podes agregarle un espacio adelante así lo toma como string/texto

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. En Excel normal habría 2 opciones: o aplicar formsto texto a la celda o precedir el número de un apóstrofe para que lo interpete como texto, pero siga siendo un número. Por ejemplo, si en una celda ponemos `'00123` en realidad para Excel será '00123'. Mejor esta solución que lo del espacio.

Comment: Si, poniendo un apóstrofe en la celda me ayudó a reconocerlo como texto. Graicas

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer esto debes importar el archivo 'csv' desde Excel y no abrirlo directamente. Con el asistente de importación, que se encuentra en él menú Datos [image: Captura de pantalla Excel].

Allí seleccionas el archivo, luego si es de ancho fijo o delimitado (junto con la codificación), con posterioridad te pedirá la división de cada columna o el delimitado (según corresponda) y si le das 'siguiente', te aparecerá una pantalla como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí seleccionas la columna de interés (code, según entiendo) y le das formato texto, con esto no elimina los ceros al inicio.

Answer (score 0):

Es inadecuado usar Excel para "ver" o validar el contenido de un archivo que esté en formato CSV, ya que por omisión Excel siempre "hace de las suyas", transformando de la información antes de insertarla en la celda y mostrarla en pantalla.

Una opción para lograr conservar los ceros a la izquierda es preceder el valor con el caracter apóstrofe (ASCII 39), pero si fuera a usar el archivo en otro lado sería información sobrante ya que no es conforme al cuasi-estándar que se espera de un archivo CSV.

Le recomiendo usar editores de texto, como NotePad++, OpenEditor y otros similares.

Existen varios editores que "leen" archivos en formato CSV y muestran en columnas los datos sin aplicar transformaciones, le recomiendo [CVSed](https://csved.sjfrancke.nl/)

Comment: Si, concuerdo completamente contigo de que es inadecuado usar excel para "ver" o validar el contenido de un archivo en formato CSV, pero digamos que no depende completamente de mi utilizar o no Excel. Ya que el cliente es el que al final de cuentas ocupa ese archivo. ¿O tal vez guardando los datos en otro formato que no sea csv, tal vez xlsx funcione? Aunque no estoy seguro, intentaré. Saludos!

Comment: Si su cliente va a usar Excel para ver la información, es posible crear desde PL/SQL.un archivo de Excel con estructura xlsx.